# VBA code unable to read the complete html within the iframe

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom, iframe

I am writing a VBA code in excel to open a webpage and read all the HTML content in the DOM explorer of the webpage and store it in a cell in the excel.

I am pasting my code below; this code skips the HTML content that is within the iframe of the main HTML. (Basically it skips the secondary HTML within the main HTML). But I need to view the complete HTML from the DOM explorer. Can someone pls help me here?

```
Sub WebPage_SourceCode()
    Dim IEapp As InternetExplorer
    Dim WebUrl As String
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection

    Set IEapp = New InternetExplorer
    WebUrl = "https://abcd.com/"

    With IEapp
        .Silent = True
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate WebUrl

        Do While .Busy = True Or .READYSTATE <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

        pagesource = IEapp.Document.body.innerHTML
        Cells(1, 1) = pagesource

 End Sub
```

I've also tried to get the elements by each iframe and store it in different cells by using the below code, but the elements within the HTML after the iframe tag is read.

```
Set Doc = IEapp.Document
        Set Elements = Doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")          

        i = 1
        For Each element In Elements
                Cells(i, 1) = element.className
                Cells(i, 2) = element.innerHTML
                Cells(i, 3) = element.outerHTML
                i = i + 1                    
        Next
```

Below is the link to the portion of the HTML. The HTML within the iframe (highlighted in red border) is skipped by VBA. Anycode before and after the iframe is read by VBA.

[Sample of Source HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3b1y.jpg)

Comment: Please use snippet tool to add html code in. Not as image. As I can't copy from that image my answer is rather short.

Comment: My question would be, why are you trying to read the document to a cell? You already have access to the DOM, can you not just retrieve whatever it is that you need directly from the page?

Comment: @Zac Good question. Lol.  Also, they may be hitting the same origin policy. Hard to say without knowing the original URL.

Comment: @QHarr : good shout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document is loaded from a different src. Try using [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)/IE
 to that src link and grab the response text.

src

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint @QHarr. I have picked up this src and written a code explicitly for this src and it worked perfectly fine as per my requirement. Thank you very much for your perfect explanation. :)